# Poisson Process and Random Walks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to simulate a random walk in 1D by graphing a Poisson process with a mean rate of 1 s^(-1), but in a randomly chosen direction (left or right).  I am trying to plot the trajectories (`x` vs `t`) with a total duration of `t = 400s`, however, I can't seem to track the `x` direction with `t` (time) properly. How can I do this? I have this so far:

```
x = [0]

t = [0]

for j in range(100):

    mean_rate = 1.0 
    d = 1.0 
    step_x = np.random.poisson(0, mean_rate)
    bern_tri = np.random.binomial(0.5,step_x)

    if bern_tri == 1:
        x.append(x[j] + d)
        t.append(t[j])
    else:
        x.append(x[j] - d)
        t.append(t[j])
plt.plot(x,t) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "track" mean in this context? Your code doesn't produce any output, so how can you tell whether it's working or not? If you're thinking "I have additional code after this loop that displays the results", please share that code, too.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, track as in for each step taken in the random process, a new position, x, occurs and simultaneously, a new time, t, tracks that position.  I tried plotting it and i kept getting a linear sequence.  And Im aiming for something that looks like this:
http://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/srep/2016/160114/srep19297/images_hires/m685/srep19297-f1.jpg

Comment: The whole question is: 'first consider a merged Poisson process with mean rate beta, and draw a sequence of waiting times from it.  Then for each of these times, we draw from a Bernoulli trial to determine whether the step at that time was rightward or leftward.  Then we make, cumulative sum of the steps, to find the complete trajectory as a function of time.  With this simulate a random walk in 1D, but in a randomly chosen direction.  Make a graph of two typical trajectories (x vs. t)  with total duration T = 400s."

Comment: I'm not too familiar with numpy and such, so maybe this is a silly suggestion, but: what if you also append values to `t`? Perhaps something like `t.append(j+1)` in the loop?

Comment: Ive tried it as well, however, I'm still obtaining a linear trajectory.

Comment: Print `t` and `x`. You''l see that `t` only contains zeros and `x` contains -1, -2, -3, ... because you never reach the case `bern_tri == 1`. This might have something to do with the inputs of `np.random.poisson` and `np.random.binomial` you use, see the NumPy docs. Both functions seem to yield zero all the time. **Besides:** 1) Take `mean_rate` and `d` out of the loop. 2) I guess what you want for `t` in the end is a simple `np.arange(401)`. 3) The random functions can generate 400 values at once, probably the whole loop is not necessary.